# asp.net gridview changing DropDownList Enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I tried to change a dropdownlist.enabled which in gridview row.

i write this code block.

```
            if (isEdit && index == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (item.RowIndex == index)
                    {
                        DataRowView rowView2 = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
                        DDL = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlLocation");
                        DDL.Enabled = true;
                        isEdit = false;
                    }
                }

             }
```

and get isEdit from  GridView1_RowEditing

like :

```
  isEdit = true;
```

and get index from row command 
like :

```
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        }
```

is anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your code down to just this:

```
if (isEdit)
{
    DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("ddlLocation");
    DDL.Enabled = true;
    isEdit = false;
 }
```